# retrieve data from forEach and send to front end node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, foreach

I have this function:

```
app.get('/dashboard', async(req, res) => {
  const customers = await stripe.customers.list();

  customers.data.forEach(customer => {
    console.log(customer.id);
  });

  // res.render('dashboard.ejs', {customer: customers})
})
```

what it does is returns all the customers from my Stripe db. However, now i want to pass the data returned from the loop, which is all of it lol, and access it on the front-end. How can i do this?

Comment: Use `res.json({customer: customers})` to send a JSON response.

Comment: As @Barmar said. Or you can use promises to make it cleaner. `stripe.customeres.list.then(c => res.json({ customer: c }))`

Comment: @Invizi It should be `=> res.json({customer: c})` to get it nested the way they want.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, made the changes.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for your comments. helped a lot

Comment: @Invizi thanks for your comments. helped a lot